# How Do I Use OAuth2.0 With JWT To Connect To Salesforce?

Tags: oauth2, python, jwt, simple-salesforce

So I'm trying to get a proof-of-concept together so I can ask my employer for access to our Salesforce (I'm a new employee and very low on the food chain, but their current workflow is just STUPID).

I've read all the documentation I can find (mostly on the official Salesforce website), and I actually managed to make a successful connection using the Salesforce CLI, but I just CANNOT seem to get it working using python.

I am including my (attempt) at a MWE, including some representations for the string values (in case that helps someone figure out what is wrong).

```
import jwt
import requests
import datetime
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from simple_salesforce.exceptions import SalesforceAuthenticationFailed
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

client_id = consumer_key = os.getenv('consumer_key')
# CONSUMER KEY

client_secret = consumer_secret = os.getenv('consumer_secret')
# CLIENT SECRET

username=os.getenv('sf_user_name')
# name@domain.tld

private_key=os.getenv('private_key')
#-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
# PRIVATE KEY
# -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

def jwt_login(consumer_id, username, private_key):
    # endpoint = 'https://justmerightnow-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com'
    endpoint = 'https://login.salesforce.com'
    jwt_payload = jwt.encode(
        {
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30),
            'iss': consumer_id,
            'aud': endpoint,
            'sub': username
        },
        private_key,
        algorithm='RS256'
    )

    result = requests.post(
        endpoint + '/services/oauth2/token',
        data={
            'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
            'assertion': jwt_payload
        },
        # adding header
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    )
    body = result.json()

    if result.status_code != 200:
        raise SalesforceAuthenticationFailed(body['error'], body['error_description'])

    return Salesforce(instance_url=body['instance_url'], session_id=body['access_token'])

sf = jwt_login(consumer_id=client_id, username=username, private_key=private_key)
```

My (current) error shows:

```
sf = jwt_login(consumer_id=client_id,username=username,private_key=private_key)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    raise SalesforceAuthenticationFailed(body['error'], body['error_description'])
simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceAuthenticationFailed: invalid_grant: audience is invalid
```

And I don't even really understand what it's talking about (all this JWT token stuff is very new to me and I'm suffering from some mental overload).

EDIT: OKay,so changing `endpoint` to simply `endpoint = 'https://login.salesforce.com'` now throws the following error:
`simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceAuthenticationFailed: invalid_request: too many scopes requested`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow - "error":"unsupported\_grant\_type"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269514/oauth-2-0-jwt-bearer-token-flow-errorunsupported-grant-type)

Comment: Double check the [scope handling](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) (search for "scope parameter" in the page) you defined for the Connected App.

Comment: @identigral The only addition/change I can identify from there is `headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}` (which I've just added), but the error remains.

Comment: @PhilW I don't see "scope parameter", but I do see "OAuth Custom Scopes" (of which I have none).

Comment: Search for that text in the Web page. It is there, I promise.

Comment: @PhilW Maybe my issue is I don't understand which web page I should be searching (and do you mean I should search in the page's source?).
`Setup > App Manager > My_Application_Name > View/Manage/Edit` pages all lack a "scope parameter" in their text (but I haven't searched source code)

Comment: No, I am talking about the link in my first comment: [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I had (when previously coming across an issue) selected ALL the scopes under `Setup > App Manager > MY_APP_NAME > Edit`

SUPER embarrassed